# Is there way to compile ATS source into JVM bytecode?

Tags: ats

I want to use ATS in a largely Java-based project. I could not find a compiler (or transpiler) from the C code generated from ATS source into Java source. Is there a way generate JVM bytecode from ATS source?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent of my knowledge, at the moment there is no published JVM bytecode generator for ATS. See the list of currently implemented ATS code generators [here](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/wiki/code-generation).

The closest to your specification might be the Clojure backend ([atscc2clj](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ats-lang-users/IDen4z1NXBw)), since there is [relatively straightforward interop between Clojure and Java](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/java/api/package-summary.html) (both being JVM-based). I haven't tested the code generation functionality myself, though, so I can comment only on availability, not on usability.